# Get select option value from HTML with php to disable input field

Tags: php

I use `select` as below:

```
<select name="account_type" required>
    <option value="">Choose Account Type</option>
    <option value="1">Asset</option>
    <option value="2">Bank</option>
    <option value="3">Capital</option>
    <option value="4">Cash</option>
    <option value="5">Expense</option>
    <option value="6">Income</option>
    <option value="7">Liability</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to catch those option values using `php` variable, and here is the important part: I will have an input field, and based on the values I want to enable/disable that input filed.
How can I do that?

Comment: what you have done so far. what you have tried to achieve it please paste your php code here.

Comment: instead `php` use `javascript` to enable/disable as `select` changes

Comment: What I've done so far is pasted over here. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: ok, so as per @Rishi told you have no need to use php you can achieve it through js or jquery.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, it doesn't run until you submit the form, so it can't enable and disable things on the fly. As others have said, you need to learn Javascript to do this.

Comment: I can do this with javascript using ajax. But the question is, how to call function by selecting an option rather than submitting a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jQuery` give your `select` an `id` like below

```
<select name="account_type" id="account" required>
    <option value="">Choose Account Type</option>
    <option value="1">Asset</option>
    <option value="2">Bank</option>
    <option value="3">Capital</option>
    <option value="4">Cash</option>
    <option value="5">Expense</option>
    <option value="6">Income</option>
    <option value="7">Liability</option>
</select>

<!--input to be disabled -->
<input type="text" id="disable">
```

jQuery

```
$('#account').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() === '1') {
    $("#disable").prop('disabled', true);
    //you can also send data to PHP here using AJAX
    //var data = {one: $(this).val()};
    //$.post( "test.php", data, function( data ) {
    //$( ".result" ).html( data );
    //});
 }else if($(this).val() === '2') {
    //code here 
 }
   //check for other values
});
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/phutis/ys9kvvhu/)

Comment: Its worked. Thank you so much. A little question, if I want to store that input value in a php variable for later use, should use like this: $_POST['disable']?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with jQuery. If you don't know jQuery, check this out: [jQuery.com](https://jquery.com/)

After you "installed" jQuery, you can use this in your js-File. I hope that you know how to create and use a js-File.

The next thing is to implement a good method for your `select`-button.

This could look like this in your js-File:

```
$('#my-select').change(function(){ // "#my-select" is the ID of your select. You need to implement a ID.
    //do stuff here, eg. 
    if ($(this).val() == '5') { //check the selected option etc.
        $("input").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $("input").prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zwvbowo/).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

html code

```
<select>
<option data-id="1">1</option>
<option data-id="2">2</option>
</select>
```

JQuery code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("select").change(function(){
        var display= $("select").val();
        if(display == 1){
        $("select").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
        }
    });
    });
```

I am not sure what you want exactly.check out this may be it will be helpful for you [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darshan_sk/3e4kuc3m/)